Jetware WordPress 4 on LEMP 7 Max Performance -- Nginx version upgrade
I downloaded Jetware WordPress 4 on LEMP 7 Max Performance and installed on an ubuntu server, out-of-the box the nginx server version is too old(still with 1.11.2), I tried to upgrade it but struggled to find any guideline or document to upgrade the nginx on the Jetware WordPress 4 on LEMP 7 Max Performance environment as the setup is customized, does anyone has similar experience that can shed some lights with me?
